# Which one is the best practice for a constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I looked at Microsoft's documentation, the best practice should be the second one. But I'm still puzzled by that. I used both constructors in my program without any problems. I would like to know what exactly the difference is?

```
public class Person
{
    // fields
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    // data accessor
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }
    // constructor
    public Person(string fn, string ln)
    {
        _firstName = fn;
        _lastName = ln;
    }
}
```

```
public class Person
{
    // fields
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    // data accessor
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { _lastName = value; }
    }
    // constructor
    public Person(string fn, string ln)
    {
        FirstName = fn;
        LastName = ln;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one is better. It makes sure that if there are side-effects (other things that happen in the getter or setter later) are complete. The first one would not call the getter or setter, which means that any additional code would not be run. Consider a case where besides setting a single value, it had an effect on other properties, like maybe setting a value that directly conflicts with another property's value or a check to make sure a value is within a certain range.

Comment: This has to be evaluated depending on the use-case. If you have auto-properties, you of course set the Property, otherwise you set either the backing field, if you want no side effects, or the Property if you want to generate actions based on the code you have in the setter(s) (and of course you have planned for this) -- You have no code in the setters here, so it's ~the same. You could use auto-properties

Comment: @KenWhite So by extension, in the class, public interfaces should also use properties instead of backing fields, because properties through setters and getters, not a single set value. But most of the time, private implementation should use backing fields. Am I right to say that?

Comment: That's something situational, as @Jimi mentioned. As a general rule, if you're writing any getter or setter, you will need backing fields, but there's not anything to say *you should always use backing fields*.

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, I think that getters and setters are both methods, and the function of the constructor is to initialize the field when this object is created. So I still think it makes more sense that the constructor should be written in the 1st form.

Comment: @K.K: As I said, that depends on what side effects the getter or setter might have. If you don't use the getter/setter, and it has side effects, that code has to be duplicated in the constructor. Duplication of code is always a poor idea, and can cause issues. What happens if the side effect behavior changes in the future, and the constructor isn't updated with the same changes?

Comment: @KenWhite I just want to unify the format of the code. Some classes have some code in the setter, and some don't. I want to write code in a uniform format. Which one is better?

Comment: @K.K: There is no *better*, and there is no *one size fits all* design. You're not reading what people are writing. What's *best* is what suits the functionality of the single class that you're writing. Each class is different, with different design and different requirements. You write code to meet the design needs, not on some arbitrary *it has to be this exact way* rule. You'll find that's the case if you look at MS's own code implementations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the class is mutable, and both first and last name are nullable, it is actually not mandatory for the fields to be set on instantiation. So you could save some typing and just do this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and instantiate it this way:

```
var instance = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
```

Personally I tend to prefer immutable classes, so I would prefer something more like this:

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly string _firstName;
    private readonly string _lastName;

    public string FirstName => _firstName;

    public string LastName => _lastName;

    public Person (string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (firstName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("FirstName");
        if (lastName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("LastName");

        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

With the immutable version you can be certain that, from very the moment of instantiation, the first and last name are valid. So the instance is always valid. With your class you can't, regardless of how you set things in the constructor.

Comment: I like the "value or throw" style for compactness: `_firstName = firstName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(firstName));`

Comment: The question is **not** about immutable/mutable/nullable but whether the _constructor_ should **a)** initialise the fields _directly_ by writing to the fields or **b)** _indirectly_ by making use of the property setters where it is the setters that write to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Microsoft is promoting the technique demonstrated in the **2nd example** to encourage the use of the *setters in the defined properties* in the event they are doing anything **beyond** assigning the value to a member field (as mentioned by Ken White above).  At the moment they are not so your puzzlement is understandable.

However, as the code grows, the properties may evolve and take on the following shape (let's assume `Person` is now implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and utilising a service transmit changes to a peer-to-peer network service like a game):

```
private readonly ISomePeerToPeerService _peerService;

public Person(string fn, string ln, ISomePeerToPeerServicepeerService peerService)
{
    _firstName = fn;
    _lastName = ln;
    _peerService = peerService;
}
    
public string LastName
{
    get { return _lastName; }
    set 
    { 
        if (Equals(_lastName, value)
            return;

        _lastName = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged()
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string memberName = null)
    {
        _peerService.Update(this); // Update peers
        
        // notify stuff
    }
}
```

...it becomes more important to ensure that all code (including the internals of `Person` to invoke these properties rather than modifying the fields directly.  If not, the custom logic won't be invoked.

Another example is if the person gets married:

```
public BankAccount SharedBankAccount { get { ... }  set { ... } }

public void MarryTheGroom(Person groom)
{
    LastName = groom.LastName;
    SharedBankAccount = groom.PersonalAccount; // he he
}
```

### Conclusion

It's quite similar to accidentally exposing fields publically and then client code modifies them directly rather than calling some method like `TransferFundsBeteenBankAccounts(x, y)`